# Linkedin shows 403 forbidden error in java script api

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to search people with company name but it displays in console as

GET [https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(num-results,people:(first-name,last-name,distance))?company-name=infosys](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search%3a%28num-results,people%3a%28first-name,last-name,distance%29%29?company-name=infosys) 403 (Forbidden) xdrpc.html?v=0.0.2000-RC8.35784-1413:1651

**My Code :**

```
 <html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: --api-key-here--
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
        authorize: true
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

   function onLinkedInLoad() {
     alert("authenticating..");
     // Listen for an auth event to occur
     IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
}

        function onLinkedInAuth() {

            IN.API.PeopleSearch()
            .fields("firstName", "lastName", "distance")
            .params({"company-name":"infosys"})
            .result(displayPeopleSearch)
            .error();

        }

    function displayPeopleSearch(peopleSearch){

        var peopleSearchDiv = document.getElementById("peoplesearch");

        var members = peopleSearch.people.values;


        for (var member in members) {
        // but inside the loop, everything is the same
        // extract the title from the members first position
            peopleSearchDiv.innerHTML += "<p>" + members[member].firstName + " " + members[member].lastName + " is a " + members[member].positions.values[0].title + ".</p>";

        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<!-- need to be logged in to use Search; if not, offer a login button -->
<script type="IN/Login"></script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found after a big battle,Linked IN has created vetted API access to people search only developers registered to that process can Access people search function